# Powershell Set-ADUser userCertificate parameter type error

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script, which essentially does the following:

```
$user = Get-ADUser $someUserName -Server $someCertServer -Properties *
$user.userCertificate |% { Set-ADUser $someUserName -Certificates @{Add=$_} }
```

It copies the cert data from a cert-server to the default server. `$user.userCertificate` is of type `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection` and `$user.userCertificate[0]` is of type `System.Byte[]`. According to the [docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx), I can pass a `Byte[]` and be good to go. By using the foreach operator in the above script, I get the Byte[].

However, Powershell fails with the error message

> the parameter certificates requires all values in the collection to be of the same type

(and underlines the `@{Add=$_}`; the message might not be 100% accurate, since I had to translate it to English). Because of the foreach operator, there is only one type: a Byte[]. What does that error message mean and how can I shove the certificate into the ADUser object?

I also tried to convert the Byte[] to a certificate object, however it ended up with the same error message:

```
$cert = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cert.Import($user.userCertificate[0])
Set-ADUser $someUserName -Certificates @{Add=$cert}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first issue I see is that you are calling on the wrong property for your example to work.

> ```
> $user.userCertificate | ForEach-Object { Set-ADUser $someUserName -Certificates @{Add=$_}}
> ```

While there is a property called `userCertificate` on that object that contains an collection of `[byte[]]`. For that code to work the way you want it to you should be using `Certificates`. `Certificates` is an collection of `Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate`

So making that change I was able to add another users certificate to my own account.

```
$certUser = Get-Aduser "someGuy" -Properties certificates
$certUser.Certificates | %{ Set-ADUser "ME" -Certificates @{Add=$_}}
```

<sup>**Note:** It is a better practice to only request the properties you *need* from AD. Using `-properties *` is a waste of effort and needless resources</sup>

While this exact scenario is not covered there is a nice write-up on the [MSDN Blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adpowershell/2009/04/26/working-with-certificates-in-active-directory-powershell/) about dealing with certs.

---

### Cert as a byte array

Now that we know `userCertificate` is a collection of byte arrays maybe we can look into how to use that.

I was having issues using the byte array with the certificate parameter for `Set-Aduser` even though it is supposed to support it. I got the error

> ```
> Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Certificates'. Values in the argument collection should be of Type: 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate'
> ```

I did get this to work but I had to cast the byte array as a cert object first which was redundant considering this appear to be what the `Certificates` property already is.

```
$certUser.Usercertificate | ForEach-Object{
    Set-ADUser "ME" -certificate @{Add=[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate]$_}
}
```

Comment: "There is no property called userCertificate"

but,... there is! I just re-checked. However, I use `-Properties *`, while you use `-Properties certificates`. It seems to make a difference and I do get the same results as you!

So, all in all, using that property change, I am able to make it work. Brilliant, thank you a lot :)

Comment: Ah, I can only award the bounty in 20h. Since you are first and your answer contains the solution, I will award it tomorrow :)

Comment: @MarcoAlka _but,... there is_ hmmm there actually is it seems. My bad. I made that assumtion because of the ldap attribute and examples on the next dont use it. it does not appear to be an alias either.... I will try and figure out the difference then. perhaps  `userCertificate` is not populated with the same data. ...... `-properties *` pulls all the properties (considered bad coding practice) I just asked for the one.

Comment: @MarcoAlka I have updated the answer which now better explains what is going on.