# Update certificates on Active Directory user profile (userCertificate)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to update an array of certificates stored on user's AD account.

I have this:

```
$allProfileRawCerts = Get-ADUser -Server example.com -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $Mail} -Property Certificates
```

Which gives

```
Certificates      : {System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, 
                    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate}
DistinguishedName : <>
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : <>
Name              : <>
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : <>
SamAccountName    : <>
SID               : <>
Surname           : <>
UserPrincipalName : <>
```

I found [Powershell Set-ADUser userCertificate parameter type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005500/powershell-set-aduser-usercertificate-parameter-type-error), which provides "add" operation:

```
$certUser.Usercertificate | ForEach-Object{
    Set-ADUser "ME" -certificate @{Add=[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate]$_}
}
```

However, what I need is not to *add*, but rather *update* - remove some certificates based on condition, then add new ones.

One approach (I think) would be to delete all certificates from user profile, create new array and update - but I really, really don't like deleting valid data in a non-atomic operation.

Also, the problem (at least for me) is that I can't filter on (rather basic) X509Certificate, but I have to convert to X509Certificate2 first:

```
$allProfileSMIMECerts = $allProfileRawCerts.Certificates |
    foreach {New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $_} |
    Where-Object { $_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -eq "Secure Email" }
```

What I need is:

1. Get list of all certificates.
2. Delete all for which `$_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -eq "Secure Email"` is true.
3. Add a new certificate.

How to do it in a nice way?

Comment: Many items in AD and Exchange, requires empty and repopulate for updating. IF the method you pull does not have and updated, then what you've surmised is your option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using following code:

```
try {
    $allProfileRawCerts = (Get-ADUser -Server example.com -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $Mail} -Property Certificates).Certificates
}
catch {
    Write-Log -ERROR "Can't contact Global AD directory, exiting..."
    exit 100
}

$handlesToRemove = ($allProfileRawCerts |
    foreach {New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $_} |
    Where-Object { $_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -eq "Secure Email" }).Handle

$objectToRemove = $allProfileRawCerts | Where-Object Handle -in $handlesToRemove

# first add the new cert
Write-Log -INFO "Adding newly minted certificate to user's AD profile."
$newCert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate

try {
    $newCert.Import("$workdir\$ticket.cer")
}
catch {
    Write-Log -ERROR "Can't import new certificate from file, exiting..."
    Write-Log -ERROR "$($PSItem.ToString())"
    exit 103
}

try {
    Get-ADUser -Server example.com -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $Mail} | 
        Set-ADUser -Credential $CACredential -Certificates @{Add=$newCert};@{Remove=$objectToRemove}
}
catch {
    Write-Log -ERROR "Can't add the new certificate to user profile, exiting..."
    Write-Log -ERROR "$($PSItem.ToString())"
    exit 104
}
Write-Log -INFO "New certificate successfully added to user's AD profile."

# now remove old certs
foreach ( $object in $objectToRemove ) { 
    Write-Log -INFO "Certificate with handle $($object.Handle) will be removed, saving to work directory."

    try {
        $null = Export-Certificate -Type CERT -Cert $cert -FilePath "$workdir\$($object.Handle).cer"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Log -FATAL "Can't save certificate to be deleted, exiting!"
        exit 101
    }

    try {
        Get-ADUser -Server example.com -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $Mail} | 
            Set-ADUser -Credential $CACredential -Certificates @{Remove=$object}
    }
    catch {
        Write-Log -ERROR "Problems contacting AD for certificate removal, exiting..."
        Write-Log -ERROR "$($PSItem.ToString())"
        exit 102
    }

    Write-Log -INFO "Certificate has been saved and removed from AD profile."
}
```

Any and all comments welcome, since I'm still a Powershell n00b.